# tkinter tab width incorrect

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, fonts

When creating text on a canvas using the `create_text` method the width of a tab is not what it should be, as indicated by `font.measure`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.font import Font

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()

font = Font(family='Arial', size=12)

s1 = "a\tb"
s2 = "a    c"
print("Width:", s1, font.measure(s1))  # Width: a        b 30
print("Width:", s2, font.measure(s2))  # Width: a    c 33

canvas.create_text(10, 10, text=s1, font=font, anchor="nw")
canvas.create_text(10, 50, text=s2, font=font, anchor="nw")

root.mainloop()
```

The results of `font.measure` suggest that the line with spaces should be a little longer, but what it displays is:

[image: Width of tab is larger than width of spaces]

Showing that the width of the tab is significantly larger than the spaces. Using different fonts will result in differently sized tabs, but still inaccurate measurements. The measured width of the text without tabs is correct.

How can I get the correct tab width? Is this a bug?

Comment: It really depends on how the *tab* character is handled.  It may be converted to *distance* in pixels in Canvas (I say *may be*), but in number of characters when printed in console.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've highlighted is due to the Canvas text object not having a `tabs` attribute.

Maybe someone knows how to work around that but usually when displaying tabulation a `tk.Text` object is used which has `font` and `tabs` attributes.

So the easiest solution is to make a `tk.Text` object T, define font and tabs,
insert your messages into T then insert T into a `Canvas` window W.

Something like this.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font

app = tk.Tk()

fixed = 1 # test Arial & Courier New
FONT = font.Font(family = ["arial", "courier new"][fixed], size = 12)
wide = 4 * FONT.measure(0)
high = FONT.metrics("linespace")
dent = (wide, tk.LEFT)

canvas = tk.Canvas(app)
canvas.grid(sticky =tk.NSEW)

s1, s2 = "a\tb\n", "a   c"

T = tk.Text(
    canvas,
    background = "SystemButtonFace",
    relief = tk.FLAT,
    font = FONT,
    tabs = dent,
    width = 20,
    height = 3,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    borderwidth = 0)

W = canvas.create_window(wide, high, window = T, anchor = tk.NW)

T.insert("1.0", s1)
T.insert("insert", s2)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not sure what the width of the tab is though. It appears to be 30 in this example, which is not the same as the first element of `dent`. Being able to change the tab width is nice though.

Answer (score 0):

Does this will help? In line 12, I just added `\t`

```
s2 = "a\tc"
```

Result:

[image]